# From where I can find the codes for ML Neural Network?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, genetics

I want to work on machine learning neural network on python, to predict genetic interactions. I am looking for hands-on learning experience on coding and producing results form public data.

Most what I find are books for business or theoretical information without practical codes. If you have any source could guide me through this I really appreciate it.

Comment: https://github.com/search?q=python%20neural%20network&type=repositories although I doubt just reading source code is any help without the theoretical knowledge.

Comment: I need both but mostly (and I prefer) to start with coding then I do theoretical

Comment: You might want to look at Andrew Ng's deep learning course (for a general and not too theoretical overview), or perhaps Andrej Karpathy if you're more interested in language modelling specifically. I would particularly recommend Andrej's first lecture from this series (https://karpathy.ai/zero-to-hero.html)

Comment: Thank you everyone, but I'm not interested in building NN, I just want to use this data https://github.com/mjflab/chinn. I have a gene of interest and I want to know how to code to predict the genetics interactions. can any one guide me to where I can start

Comment: I don't want to create NN, I don't want to build neural network. I just want to learn how to code to produce a prediction. I will import CHINN data in python, then I should do coding in order to have an output. So my question is what are the codes and where I can find a source to learn how to implement them ?